# SPGO - RETRIEVE FOLDER NOT FOUND

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-deployment

I'm not able to connect SPGO to my Office 365 SharePoint site

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVsIX.png

My SPGo.json

{
"sourceDirectory": "src",
"sharePointSiteUrl": "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites",
"publishingScope": "Major",
"authenticationType": "Digest"

}

my login and password are correct because I can log in with it at https://www.office.com/
Is it some vscode setting?

Comment: Maybe you write site wrong "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites". Try adding name of site for ex "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/SITENAME"

Comment: I already informed the name of the site too

"sharePointSiteUrl": "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/Curso",

Comment: Look at configuration of spgo https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SiteGo.spgo and get >SPGo: Populate Workspace. You can get all controls pressing ctr+shift+p in VScode and type spgo

Comment: Here you have all steps https://www.chrishasz.com/spgo/general/getting-started-with-spgo.html